# dot(.) in the field names are assumed to be array elements

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Field name is having dot`(.)` char is splitting the values and it is not taking the value from textbox.
For example, the field name is `FirstName.` then in the values json it is taking it as `"FirstName.":"","FirstName":[]`. Even if the field has the dot(.) char at somewhere at the middle also behaving the same as I mentioned.
Deep fields with a name prop containing digits are assumed to be array elements. For example, if you place a field with `name="FirstName."` in a , foo is assumed to be an array, not a standard object.

Sandbox Link
https://codesandbox.io/s/rjo85xwqoo

Expected behavior is to take the value from the textbox and map it to the field.
A Form would represent a plain object, not an array. Any nested field names would show up as properties on that object

Comment: Um, do you need the dot in the name?

Comment: Yes,Thats my requirement. For example a field name could be "Contact No."

Comment: I just think you're making things complicated for yourself. As the programmer, you're in control of the variable names, so just choose not to have a dot. What if you wanted a " in the variable name, or spaces...?

Comment: @lavanya, you confuse the appointment of attribute 'name' for Field. The main goal of it - to map values to the object, not to display it in some way. Use `Label` to display field name, and `name` to map it.

Comment: I think Lee and Alex are correct in this instance.

Comment: dot in the field name is my requirement from customer, So I need help to resolve this as redux form framework doesn't support.